# removing white space between images using html

Tags: html

After reading a number of answers to this problem, it seems none of them have solved the problem.  I'm trying to send and email via VerticalResponse and they use html.  The message is created stacking multiple images, each with links, but it's supposed to look like one image.  Problem is that the preview looks good and so does viewing it in a webpage, but email display shows white space between each image.  See http://jsfiddle.net/xMW7N/42/ for code.  Please help!

```
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center; ">
        <span style="font-size:8pt;"><a href="website"><img align="normal" alt="Facebook - MetricRunFest" border="0" height="126" hspace="-20" name="FB" src="https://141790a61d-custmedia.vresp.com//a091cd9b91/Top.jpg?0.7593426643870771" style="width: 600px; height: 126px;" title="Facebook - MetricRunFest" vspace="0" width="600" /></a></span><br />
        <span style="font-size:8pt;"><a href=website"><img align="normal" alt="Metric Runners - Online Photos" border="0" height="205" hspace="-2" name="MetricRunFest - Online Photos" src="https://141790a61d-custmedia.vresp.com//a091cd9b91/Message%20Blank.jpg?0.8384064519777894" style="width: 600px; height: 205px;" title="Metric Runners - Online Photos" vspace="0" width="600" /><br />
        <img align="normal" alt="website" border="0" height="127" hspace="-2" src="https://141790a61d-custmedia.vresp.com//a091cd9b91/Message%20Blank_UpsideDown%209.jpg?0.44395816628821194" style="width: 600px; height: 127px;" title="website" vspace="0" width="600" /></a></span><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers treat white space differently. It's good to write everything on 1 line if possible, with no needless spaces or newlines.You can try like this:-

```
  <span><img src="image1.jpg"></span><span><img src="image2.jpg"></span><span><img src="image3.jpg"></span>
```

Comment: I can't agree that it is "best" to keep it on one line, however it does solve some white-space problems when it comes to email, because most email-clients are rubbish.

Comment: I just think we have to differentiate between development for emails and for web/others, as there are some odd quirks you have to work around when developing for an email client – one being this weird white-space bug, which is some times solved by a one liner.

Answer (score 1):

There is a breaking space between every image which is part of the problem. Also, try giving the images `display: block` style.

http://jsfiddle.net/xMW7N/47/

Comment: Thanks!  It's looks good and displays correct until it ends up in gmail.  Maybe that's the problem because otherwise it looks great.

Answer (score 0):

Everything I have seen on html emails, and from the experience I have in doing them myself, the best option is using tables, unforunately. It can really help with all layout problems.

I'd recommend reading http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails for a lot of tips, including an entire section on images. Especially using `img {display:block;}` for Hotmail and `align` such as `<img src="image.jpg" align="right">` instead of floats.

Not that you are necessarily doing those parts wrong, but they are good to remember in general.